# What kind of fastener should I use to hang things on cabinets?

Tags: walls, fastener

I have cabinets that hang down in the middle of my kitchen, above the island, and would like to mount things on the back of them (it's a metal rod from Ikea from which I'm going to hang pots and pans, so a decent amount of weight - basically something like [this](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/90011396#/50022764/), but about 5 feet long:

[image]

I'm wondering how exactly I should mount it to the back of the cabinets.  I figure I can:

- screw right into the cabinet wall
- drill holes for anchors into the cabinet wall, and then screw into those (but the cabinet wall is not very thick, maybe 1/2 or 3/4 inch (standard, I assume)
- drill holes into the cabinet wall and then attach with nuts and bolts
- something else?

What's the best way to do this?  I couldn't find anything by searching; I guess this isn't a very common thing since most peoples' cabinets' back walls are, well, against the walls in their kitchens.

Comment: can you post a photo showing the cabinets & the ceiling? Then indicate on the photo where you would prefer to have the rod hung. Also is it an option with the system you're buying to cut the rod to an exact length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would drill your holes for the rack through your cabinet, then drill some counter-sink holes on the inside of your cabinet so your bolts are flush with the inside.  You can find some flat headed bolts to use for this at any hardware store.  Have the head of your bolt on the inside of the cabinet and secure it with a lock washer and nut.  You should not need anything too thick as far as bolts go for this.  You idea on how to mount them will be fine.  The bad thing is that now you will have holes in your cabinet, so if you do not like it or if you want to remove it, you have just ruined your cabinets in a sense.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  Good point though about ruining the cabinets.  Would it be preferable to mount this on the ceiling then?

Comment: If you are tall enough :) but yes you can fix the ceiling holes cant fix the holes in the cabinets.  I am sure it will look nice either way.

Comment: I forgot to add that the only thing about attaching it to the ceiling is only one side will hit a joist.  If you have a one story, and you want to take the trouble, good carpenters will lay deadwood around the areas where your cabinets are mounted.  You can go into the attic (if it is a one story) and see if you have something to put screws in.  I would not trust drywall anchors for this.  If there is not, then you might only hit one side of the bracket with a joist.  That might not be enough support depending on the weight of your pots and pans.